# Getting properties from the store without missing their types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript, zustand

I have this setup for Redux (Zustand) store

```
type StateType = keyof DatasetSlice | keyof GlobalSlice
type Slices = GlobalSlice & DatasetSlice

const setStore = set => ({
    ...datasetSlice(set),
    ...globalSlice(set),
})

const useStore = create(devtools<Slices>(setStore, { enabled: true, name: 'Core store' }))

export const useGetStates = (stateKeys: StateType[]) =>
    useStore(
        state =>
            Object.assign(
                {},
                ...stateKeys.map(stateKey => {
                    return { [stateKey]: state[stateKey] }
                })
            ),
        shallow
    )
```

useGetStates is used to fetch data from the store, like this

```
const { backButtonTarget, invitedUsers } = useGetStates(['backButtonTarget', 'invitedUsers'])
```

The problem is that fetched variables (**backButtonTarget**, **invitedUsers**) have **ANY** type, but I need their types as they are defined in the store. Any ideas how it can be solved here?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to see your issue and only your issue.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mp0O6m) solve your problem? If yes, I will write an answer with an explanation; If not what am I missing?

Comment: Hei wonderflame, Thank you so much for your example. It worked for me and now the code in the production server. So you can create an answer and I will choose it as the solution! :) Have a nice day!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by adding the generic parameters to `useGetStates`:

```
export const useGetStates = <T extends StateType[]>(
  stateKeys: T,
): { [K in T[number]]: Slices[K] } =>
  useStore(
    (state) =>
      Object.assign(
        {},
        ...stateKeys.map((stateKey) => {
          return { [stateKey]: state[stateKey] };
        }),
      ),
    shallow,
  );
```

The crucial part is the return type which takes the elements from the passed array and assigns their slice type as a value:
`{ [K in T[number]]: Slices[K] }`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&ts=5.0.4#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)